# Operation on Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

As an example, suppose that I take $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and map them to

$\begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^4$

What is such an operation called? I know I have seen it numerous times, but never with a name associated to it.

Comment: It is informally called stacking, perhaps concatenation (not that common). It also depends on writing vectors as columns or rows.

Comment: @user251257 Is this stacking accompanied by a nice notation, such as we see with direct sums, tensors, etc?

Comment: many just write $(x,y)$ even if $x,y$ are vectors. Some write $(x^T, y^T)^T$ to emphasize that these are columns.

Comment: @user251257 Also, would you happen to know if this stacking operation has been study at all? I can't seem to find much. It seems that it might have some  nice properties; e.g., stacking each basis vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the zero vector produces the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$.

Comment: It is pretty boring. There is a natural isomorphism between $\mathbb C^m \times \mathbb C^n$ and $\mathbb C^{m+n}$

Comment: @user251257 Ah, so this stacking map just reduces to a map between $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$? Is that the meaning of your remark about the natural isomorphism?

Comment: stacking is this isomorphism. And you should parenthesize double superscripts, as it's ambiguous.